# r - Map overlaps plot borders in complex layout

Tags: r, layout, maps, par

I'm going to create a more complex graph with R showing values of a variable on 6 maps (ordered in 2 columns and 3 rows).

However, once I execute the code shown below, the first map always exceeds its plot borders as shown in the attached image.

```r
require(maps)

layout(matrix(c(14,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,
                 4,  8,  8,  8,  8, 11, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15,
                 4,  8,  8,  8,  8, 11, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15,
                 4,  8,  8,  8,  8, 11, 11, 11, 11,  7, 17,
                 5,  9,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 12, 12,  7, 17,
                 5,  9,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 12, 12,  7, 17,
                 5,  9,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 12, 12,  7, 17,
                 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13,  7, 17,
                 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13, 16, 16,
                 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13, 16, 16
), nrow=10, byrow=T))

par(mar=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "observed", cex=2)

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "estimated", cex=2)

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, paste(4478, "BP"), cex=2)

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "autosomal", cex=2, srt=90)

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "mitochondrial", cex=2, srt=90)

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "Y-chromosomal", cex=2, srt=90)

par(mar=c(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1))
Col = colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))
image(1, seq(0, 1, length=1000), matrix(1:1000, nrow=1), col=Col(1000), axes=F ,xlab="", ylab="")
box()
axis(4, at=c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), las=2, cex.axis=1.3)

par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot.new()

plot.new()

plot.new()

plot.new()
text(0.7, 0.5, "Asian ancestry", cex=2, srt=90)
```

[image]

How can I prevent that the first image overlaps its borders and is shown correctly (like the other map plots)?

Comment: What is `'i'` ?

Comment: @jay.sf You can ignore. But it is a whole number from 0 to 200. I edited out of my initial code. Sorry for this fault!

Answer (score 1):

`maps::map` seems to internally override the `par(mar(.))` you've defined. Defining in front of each `map()` works.

*altered `map` part of your code:*

```
par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)

par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
map("world2",xlim=c(90,255),ylim=c(-50,35),fill=T)
```

**Produces:**

[image]

Comment: Well, now they look identical. But it doesn't really work. Now all countries are fully drawn and the plots are not cut where they should end ...

Comment: @Anti This is because you have the same `xlim/ylim` everywhere. try e.g. `xlim=c(50,200)` for one plot.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. The main problem doesn't change if I use different lims. Any idea how else I could make the plots look I want them to look like (identical and like the maps in the 2nd column in my image)?

Comment: @Anti No, _same_ `*lims`, not different. Just define desired `*lims` once and use them for all plots, so they'll look the same.

Comment: You mean that I have to define the xlim & ylim extern? How can I do that? Maybe you could show the solution ...?! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Anti Look, you have six identical plots, just use everywhere the same `xlim/ylim` in all plots, man.

Comment: @Anti Exactly, now change all of them simultaneously, what happens?

Comment: It plots another region with all maps still going out of the predefined borders.